# Why does my print have this unusual pattern?

Tags: print-quality

Just started 3D printing. Switched from a 0.4 mm nozzle to a 0.2 mm nozzle and am printing my first object. It has this pattern/inconsistency. Thinking it might be temperature variation but not sure. Anyone know what it is?

[image: Image of a 3D printed comb with usual pattern]

I changed the speed to 60 % cause not enough was coming out at a time, it improved the results. Layer height 0.2 mm but it may be a little off from because of the leveling. I increased flow 15 % just now and seems to be printing better with more adhesion.

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Did you change the speed? Your print shows signs of underextrusion. What is the layer height?

Comment: Yes I changed the speed to 60% cause not enough was coming out at a time, it improved the results. Layer height 0.2 but it may be a little off from because of the leveling. I increased flow 15% just now and seems to be printing better with more adhesion. So underextrusion was the problem I agree. Thx for the timely response!

Comment: How does layer height relate to extrusion?

Comment: You extrude volume, so layer height and print width make up the volume you extrude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layer height should be max. 3/4 of the nozzle width, so you should print at max. 0.15 mm layer height with a 0.2 mm nozzle. So the problem is that you are using a too large of a layer height (0.2 mm). If you push more flow it appears to work, but, for the wrong reasons.

With a layer height as large as the nozzle width, you extrude cylinders/tubes with much space between the perimeters, by increasing the flow percentage you somewhat flatten the tubes, but it is better to lower the layer height.

Comment: Thank you Oscar! Very informative